# I can't send libre office document as attachments

Tags: libreoffice, thunderbird, email

On a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04.1, with thunderbird 38.5.1, a revision of LibreOffice 4.2, LO 4.4.7.2 and LO 5.04.2 fail to attach documents from the File|Send|Email ... options. Thunderbird's composer appears, with the correct subject line, but the attachment does not show nor is it transmitted.

I have another machine running LO 4.4.7.2 and TB 38.5.1 on Ubuntu 12.04.3 works as expected. The Nautilus context menu "Email" option has failed too but may be unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

Open LibreOffice, navigate to <kbd>Tools</kbd> -> <kbd>Options</kbd> -> <kbd>Internet</kbd> -> Email and set (eg. Thunderbird or Evolution as) default email client (usually located in `/usr/bin/thunderbird` & `/usr/bin/evolution`).