# LibreOffice installed from Snap on Ubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: 20.04, libreoffice, snap

Using LibreOffice 7 (Installed from Ubuntu Software. Source: snap) on Ubuntu 20.04. When I use "Email document" or "Email document as PDF", LibreOffice would open a new message Thunderbird window, with the filename in the subject. I searched around, and found [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/731215/i-cant-send-libre-office-document-as-attachments?), and followed that direction to add `/usr/lib/thunderbird/thunderbird` to the Email settings. Now I don't even get a Thunderbird pop-up. So I installed the older version of LibreOffice Writer from the main Ubuntu package source. It doesn't work any better there.

Can anyone help me troubleshoot this problem? Thank you in advance.

LibreOffice version info:

```
Version: 7.0.2.2
Build ID: 3a01483fc371ab18cfca4bab0d636937da5eaf70
CPU threads: 4; OS: Linux 5.4; UI render: default; VCL: gtk3
Locale: en-CA (en_CA.UTF-8); UI: en-US
Calc: threaded
```

Comment: On 18.04 LTS with configured Thunderbird and deb-packaged Libreoffice 7.0.4 from [their PPA](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) it works as expected. You have to remove/undo your custom settings to start over with deb-version.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by removing my custom settings to start over with the deb version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is due to the confinement of the snap version. Such integration issues are common with snap and flatpak. Applications installed through these systems run in a sandboxed environent.

If this issue is critical to your workflow, then do not install the snap version. You may use the default version of the Ubuntu version you use, or use a LibreOffice PPA if you need the latest version.